# Numbered sections in unnumbered chapters + ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, luatex

I want to have numbered sections in an unnumbered chapter.

This is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\section{First numbered section in unnumbered chapter}
\section{Second numbered section in unnumbered chapter}

\chapter{First numbered chapter}
\section{First numbered section in numbered chapter}

\end{document}
```

This is a preview of the compiled Table of Contents: 
[image: Compiled ToC]

As you can see the numbered sections have leading zeroes in the Table of Contents. How can I delete the leading zeros? Of course I want to achieve the same in the actuel text.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily change the definition of `\thesection` (no guarantee this won't break anything...)

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
\section{First numbered section in unnumbered chapter}
\section{Second numbered section in unnumbered chapter}
\endgroup

\chapter{First numbered chapter}
\section{First numbered section in numbered chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Correct answer, thank you very much!